# How to give path correctly to ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

**Problem:**

I have created an angular application. There I am using ng2-pdf-viewer. I  accessed it on an HTML file like this.

```
<pdf-viewer
      [src]="https://myback.mydomain.lk/{{gov?.source_pdf_ref}}"
      [render-text]="true"
      style="display: block;"
    ></pdf-viewer>
```

The problem that I faced is I am rendering path to pdf file dynamically. The thing I have done cause to this error.

> Uncaught Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
>           Statement: //myback.mydomain.lk.lk/{{gov?.source_pdf_ref}} located at ng:///UserLayoutModule/GovenmentTabComponent.html@110:6
>       at _AstToIrVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitQuote (compiler.js:7380)
>       at Quote.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.Quote.visit (compiler.js:6206)
>       at convertPropertyBinding (compiler.js:7084)
>       at compiler.js:22230
>       at Array.map ()
>       at createUpdateStatements (compiler.js:22226)
>       at compiler.js:22211
>       at Array.map ()
>       at ViewBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (compiler.js:22205)
>       at ViewBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder.build (compiler.js:21677)

I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem on the internet but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this Issue or suggests a good way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix property binding and interpolation:

Try this one:

```
[src]="'https://myback.mydomain.lk/' + gov?.source_pdf_ref"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<pdf-viewer
  src="https://myback.mydomain.lk/{{gov?.source_pdf_ref}}"
  [render-text]="true"
  style="display: block;"
></pdf-viewer>
```